# Forge Model derivative fails for large IFC files

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I was trying to use model derivative API for translating fairly large (~6GB) IFC file.

I've used chunked upload for uploading file, and successfully finished uploading file to the server.

However, after submitting job, model derivative process has exited with following message:

`messages":[{"type":"error","message":"Unrecoverable exit code from extractor: -1073741829","code":"TranslationWorker-InternalFailure"}]`

I was not able to correctly identify the issue further more;
Would you please help me debug the issue please?

If you need URN and the original file, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you consider providing the URN and a reproducible IFC model to forge.help [AT] autodesk [DOT] com and quoting my name in the email? I'm glad to help you pass it to our engineering team for insights. **Note. Please remove confidential data or information from anything you want to send to us, thanks!**

Comment: Thanks. I'll send it to you via email after confirmation from my team. Just to check, is there a maximum file size limit on Model derivative translation?

Comment: Theoretically, the answer is no as I know, but there is a storage limit 5GB on your apps' OSS bucket for a trial account or basic subscription (100 C.C.), not BIM360's bucket. Did you upload it to BIM360?

Comment: Oh I see, No I have not uploaded using BIM360, but using OSS bucket directly using rest API. I think that may be root cause of the problem

Comment: To narrow down the issue, I would advise you to check the file sizes of the same IFC on your disk and on the Forge server as my answer below. If the file sizes are matched, please send your IFC URN to Forge Help. I'm glad to help you consult with our engineering team, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Commonly, the default storage size of the Forge OSS buckets for each developer account is limited to 5GB as I know, please see details [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/pricing).

If your model file size exceeds this limit, the total size of the uploaded model might be incomplete. An easy to check the total uploaded file size in bytes is call [GET buckets/:bucketKey/objects](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-GET/) or [GET buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectName/details](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-details-GET/). In the response, the `size` attribute is the file size uploaded onto Forge server. You can compare it with the file in your computer disk.

```
{
    "bucketKey": "apptestbucket",
    "objectId": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:apptestbucket/test.ifc",
    "objectKey": "test.ifc",
    "sha1": "e9d93eb76f98f60b2b79d4e8e848c556a99fdf8e",
    "size": 88167,
    "location": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/urn:adsk.objects:os.object:apptestbucket/test.ifc"
}
```